# Laravel migration value from null to string

Tags: mysql, laravel, nullable, laravel-migrations

I have a DB with a column of **null** values but now I want to change it for **nullable(false)**.

Doing a migration I tried

`$table->string('route',50)->nullable(false)->default('000 route')->change();`

but it says

`SQLSTATE[01000]: Warning: 1265 Data truncated for column 'route' at row 1 (SQL: ALTER TABLE address CHANGE route VARCHAR(50) DEFAULT '000 route' NOT NULL COLLATE utf8mb4_unicode_ci)`

Is there any way to do it using Laravel migration?

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0):

There is also another way to do it, which is by dropping and the column, and recreate a new column, for example, to drop the table:

```
  $table->dropColumn('route');
```

and try to recreate the column again:

```
 $table->string('route', 50)->default('000 route');
```

I hope this is helpful for you.

Comment: Sure everything is helpfull!